# Invalid partition table after triple boot

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub, linux-mint

My setup was running fine with windows 7, Linux mint 17.2 and Kali linux. I was using mint's grub2. Only one HDD.

Then I reinstalled Kali (due to changing partitions stucture a bit: created an additional swap partition) and as I prefer mint's grub style, I told Kali to NOT install grub in MBR of the HDD. It asked where do I want to install the grub and I installed it on a random USB drive to get rid of it.

Now when booting up I'm getting the "Invalid partition table!" error, which is displayed right after the BIOS splash screen.

I guess Kali still deleted the old grub from the MBR of my HDD?

Then I used mint live USB drive to reinstall grub (according to this http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/245) and everything seemed to succeed.

But I still get the "Invalid partition table!" error. What could be the problem?

EDIT: Ran the bootinfoscript (http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/)

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .
 => Syslinux MBR (3.00-3.35) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Kali GNU/Linux 2.0
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 4.07
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32776 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048       206,847       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2             206,848   924,803,071   924,596,224   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3         924,805,118 1,465,147,391   540,342,274   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1,402,064,896 1,418,274,815    16,209,920  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6         924,805,120 1,402,064,895   477,259,776  83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1,418,276,864 1,457,336,319    39,059,456  83 Linux
/dev/sda8       1,457,338,368 1,465,147,391     7,809,024  82 Linux swap / Solaris


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 8011 MB, 8011120640 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 973 cylinders, total 15646720 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1    *          2,048    15,646,719    15,644,672   c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        2C52EE4952EE177C                       ntfs       System Reserved
/dev/sda2        343AF1F23AF1B0CA                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        63807e5a-5d56-47d9-92eb-1bbad9a20412   swap       
/dev/sda6        0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5   ext4       
/dev/sda7        79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d   ext4       
/dev/sda8        10837372-304f-47a8-bb4e-724976945ed2   swap       
/dev/sdb1        7C01-B8DA                              vfat       MINT

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sdb1        /cdrom                   vfat       (ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/06_mint_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=white/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/06_mint_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic root=UUID=0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5' {
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit, with Linux 3.16.0-38-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-38-generic-advanced-0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic root=UUID=0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit, with Linux 3.16.0-38-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-38-generic-recovery-0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-38-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic root=UUID=0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_lupin ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_lupin ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-2C52EE4952EE177C' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  2C52EE4952EE177C
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 2C52EE4952EE177C
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux 2.0 (2.0) (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765 ro quiet
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux 2.0 (2.0) (on /dev/sda4)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765' {
    menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64--f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765 ro quiet
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64--f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765 ro quiet
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda4)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64-root=UUID=f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765 ro single-f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765' {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=f066461b-de6a-4e20-b326-493a19ee8765 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    }
}

set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=0dddccca-ecd3-4ef9-a660-7ec5865232d5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=cee5ac73-ffd4-49ee-a0cb-48eb741d4eab none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=========================== sda7/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos7'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos7'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d ro  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Kali GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d' {
    menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.0.0-kali1-amd64-advanced-79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d ro  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Kali GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class kali --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.0.0-kali1-amd64-recovery-79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos7'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos7 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos7 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos7  79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.0.0-kali1-amd64 root=UUID=79a616f3-b384-4020-a26a-467053ae764d ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.0.0-kali1-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

<snip>
```

Deleted some lines from the end to stay in the character limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My computer (Dell Latitude e6430) couldn't boot from a logical partition (even though I was using GRUB 2). Made a partition scheme such that I booted from a primary partition and everything worked out fine.